# Can I functionally concatenate a number and string?

Tags: casting, functional-programming, concatenation, d, phobos

I am trying to make a pure function that embeds a number in a string.  The obvious concatenation methods do not work:

```
pure string foo(immutable int bar)
{
    return "Number: " ~ bar; // Error: strings and ints are incompatible.
    return "Number: " ~ to!string(bar); // Error: to() is impure.
}
```

Is there a clean, functional way to concatenate a number and string?  I would like to avoid writing my own concatenation or conversion function, but I will if I have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a long-standing problem with *to!*. (See [this](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4850) bugreport.)

As far as I can tell, there are no matching pure functions in Phobos. I am afraid you are on your own.

---

**Edit from the OP:** I used a function like this one to convert `uints` to `strings`.

```
import std.math: log10;

pure string convert(uint number)
{
    string result;
    while (log10(number) + 1 >= 1)
    {
        immutable uint lastDigit = number % 10;
        result = cast(char)('0' + lastDigit) ~ result;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```